# How do I create Dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have the below code and the dataframe only include the latest file parse on my
list. How can I get a full list ?

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath,encoding="utf8"))
    text=(soup.body.find('div', {'class':[Class]}).text)
    text=sent_tokenize(text)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": text})
df
```

Comment: Assuming that every line below the for loop is indented, it appears that you're overwriting the DataFrame df in each iteration (hence being left with only the last one). Instead you should create an empty list, and append df to it each iteration.

Comment: Exactly I'm tried to create a loop wihtin the loop, in order to append the dataframe...but without any success

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of DataFrames or concatenate all of them in a single DataFrame? EDIT: also, what is in your "text" variable? Is it a list/array? That's what pandas needs to initialize a DataFrame from a dict.

Comment: That's right..I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dataframe outside the loop, inside the loop create a data frame for each file and append it to the empty dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath,encoding="utf8"))
    text=(soup.body.find('div', {'class':[Class]}).text)
    text=sent_tokenize(text)
    dfText = pd.DataFrame({"Text": text})
    df = df.append(dfText)

print(df)
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Comment: I pasted and copy your solution but the result is empty

Comment: Slight mistake in the code I posted, I've updated my original answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Append your results in a list then convert them to a dataframe:

```
lst_text = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath,encoding="utf8"))
    text=(soup.body.find('div', {'class':[Class]}).text)
    text=sent_tokenize(text)
    lst_text.append({"Text": text})

df = pd.DataFrame(lst_text)
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a list of DataFrames, try this:

```
df_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath,encoding="utf8"))
    text=(soup.body.find('div', {'class':[Class]}).text)
    text=sent_tokenize(text)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": text})
    df_list.append(df)
df_list
```